# Virtualbox guest os from raw windows 10 drive

Tags: kvm-virtualization

system windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot.
Can I use a bootable windows 10 drive as qemu/kvm guest and not give up the ability to dual boot?

Comment: In pure theory, yes.  In practicality, no.  Note that I say "in practicality, no", because the virtualized environment will have **different hardware and drivers** which your Windows 10 will not have, and as such it will not behave as you expect it to.

Comment: I vaguely remember making WinXP to run from raw disk with KVM, but don't remember details or results. Anyway, you might be interested [in this question/answer](https://superuser.com/q/415482#is-it-possible-to-run-a-windows-partition-as-a-vm)

Comment: Even if you solve the driver issue, the (virtual) hardware will be so different that Windows will claim (not without reason) that it is not genuine. You'll have to reactivate Windows every time you switch back and forth, and MS will eventually stop allowing it. Then you're stuck with a Windows installation you won't be able to use at all.